# Best way to register multiple people for an event - golf tournament

Tags: civievent

I'm looking to do create an event for a golf tournament and I'd like to set the number of participants being registered based on the selection in the price set.

Ex. choose foursome in price set, it would show 4 participants to register for the event.

Is this possible?  We do have Webform on Drupal, but I'm not well versed in using that.

p.s. A work around seems to be to have the user select the number of participants they are registering, then only have one option in the price set for "single golfer" then each participant would have that price automatically.  I just think this would be confusing for end users.

Answer (score 1):

In your Price Set you should be able to set each line item to be specified to count as a different number of Participants.

**Participant Count**
Enter a value here if you want to increment the number of registered participants per unit against the maximum number of participants allowed for this event. For example, if this price field is for a table at a fundraiser which seats eight people, you would set Participant Count to 8.

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't allow me to collect demographic info on the number of participants I entered in the participant count.  If I enter 4 participants, I need to collect info for all 4 participants.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Drupal Webform then that is the most robust solution - it can do exactly what you want.

Here are some instructions for how to set up a Webform to do event registration: https://docs.civicrm.org/webform-civicrm/en/latest/examples/simpleevent/